# Как добавить запись в Postgresql с использованием psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, insert

Есть таблица blacklist:

```
Column      Type                   Modifiers 
id          integer                not null default nextval('blacklist_id_seg, regclass) 
name        character varying(255) not null
camp_id     integer                not null 

Indexes:
    "blacklist_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id) 
    "blacklist_68a30fb" btree (camp_id)
Foreign-key constraints: 
    "blacklist camp_id_42440e51_fk_campaign id. FOREIGN KEY (camp_id) REFERENCES campaign(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Таблица blacklist имеет внешний ключ на таблицу campaign.

При создании записи получаю `camp_id`:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO campaign (camp_id, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id", (campaign_number, datetime.datetime.now()))
connect.commit()
camp_id = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Далее пытаюсь создать запись в blacklist:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO blacklist (camp_id, name) VALUES (%d, %s)", (camp_id, site))
connect.commit()
```

В campaign запись создается и id я получаю, но в blacklist создать запись не могу. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А почему не можете? Что мешает?

Comment: Я не знаю что мешает, в бд записей нет в blacklist. Я просто не знаю, как с внешними ключами тут работать. Мб что-то надо списком передавать, или нужным типом, или вообще синтаксис не такой...Раньше с ORM работал(джанга) там все на объектах и попроще

Comment: Ну, сообщение об ошибке какое-нибудь есть?

Comment: Решил проблему..вместо %d надо было %s !!!странно, по идее id числового типа,а не строкового..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых мне совершенно непонятно, почему вам требуется получать от курсора значение camp_id, когда вы его и так в явном виде передаёте в запросе.

Во-вторых, при передаче иерархических изменений в БД лучше это делать одной транзакцией. Ваш код должен бы выглядеть так:

```
# вставляем данные в campaign, только нужные поля, ключевые и так сгенерятся из sequence
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO campaign (timestamp) VALUES (%s) RETURNING camp_id", [datetime.datetime.now()])
# смотрим результат вставки, должно быть 'INSERT 0 1'
print(cursor.statusmessage)
camp_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # получаем новый идентификатор
# вставляем наконец данные в зависимую таблицу
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO blacklist (camp_id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)", (camp_id, site))
# все манипуляции с данными закончены, можно подтвердить изменения
connection.commit()
```

Ну и в третьих - зачем давать полям таблицы названия из зарезервированных слов (это я про timestamp). Таким образом можно напарываться на очень странные ошибки в самых неожиданных местах.